# Application.OnTime VBA without closing and opening excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro using Application.OnTime macro that works if I manually execute the macro.  I'm trying to automate this process so I don't have to write Application.OnTime in
 "This Workbook"  or (Private Sub Workbook_Open()   Most of you do this because you can have windows scheduler open the workbook at a certain time which starts the macros on open.  I CANNOT USE SCHEDULER.

Because I am not able to use windows scheduler I will keep the workbook open and the timer should refresh my data then Call "my Macro"  at a certain time everyday.

Comment: what happens if you don't close the workbook and re-open it? Do you get an error message? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: Thanks David, I reworded the question.  I can't use windows scheduler in my remote environment therefore the standard "call Macro on Open Workbook" method won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a timer to run your Macro.  It's easy to modify it to check the current time and then run if you want.  :-)

http://visualbasic.about.com/od/learnvba/a/vbatiming1.htm

Cheers, LC

Comment: Thanks LC, it seems like you understood my vague question.  Nobody else did.  You're answer is great.    Question:  how do I make it run everyday with the count down timer while not having to click the execute button?  the workbook will stay open.  (can't use windows scheduler)